# Disabled Flex data grid with active scroll bars

Tags: apache-flex

I have a data grid in flex that is set to disabled. I have set it disable to indicate to the user that this is read only data. This works great in most cases but for some reason the scroll bars get disabled too.

My question is can I set the data grid disabled and still have it scrollable, or am I simply trying to have my cake and eat it too?

More info: You can scroll with the scroll wheel but not with the up or down arrows on the scroll bar. The scroll indicator is also hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `editable=false`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. However I think this is for use with inline editors. The items in the grid still highlight on mouse over, that is one of the main things I need to get rid of.

Comment: then you can play with the `selectionMode` property